# Get the data of the Access database in the VSTO add-in project

Tags: ms-word, vsto, add-in

I created a VSTO Add-in project and want to get the data from Table1 from a database named Database1.

Click the Next and Previous buttons to scroll through the database records.

I am using an Access database. I have successfully connected to the database, but the code is in error when accessing the data.

Below is my code：

```
public partial class ThisAddIn { 
    private Table1 Table1;  // 'Table1' error
    private AdventureWorksLTDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter customerTableAdapter; //'' AdventureWorksLTDataSetTableAdapterserror
    private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource customerBindingSource;
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.RichTextContentControl customerContentControl;
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.Button button1;   //'Controls'  error
    private Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.Button button2;  //'Controls'  error

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Table1 = new Table1(); // 'Table1' error
        this.customerTableAdapter = new AdventureWorksLTDataSetTableAdapters.CustomerTableAdapter();
        this.customerTableAdapter.Fill(this.Table1.Customer);
        this.customerBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource();
        Word.Document currentDocument = this.Application.ActiveDocument;

        Document extendedDocument = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(currentDocument);
        extendedDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
        extendedDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.InsertParagraphBefore();
        extendedDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.Text =
            "The companies listed in the AdventureWorksLT database:   \n";
        extendedDocument.Paragraphs[2].Range.Text = "  ";

        Word.Range range1 = extendedDocument.Paragraphs[2].Range.Characters.First;
        Word.Range range2 = extendedDocument.Paragraphs[2].Range.Characters.Last;
        Word.Range range3 = extendedDocument.Paragraphs[1].Range.Characters.Last;
        this.button1 = extendedDocument.Controls.AddButton(range1, 60, 15, "1");  //'AddButton' error
        this.button1.Text = "Previous";
        this.button2 = extendedDocument.Controls.AddButton(range2, 60, 15, "2");  //'AddButton' error
        this.button2.Text = "Next";

        this.customerContentControl = extendedDocument.Controls.AddRichTextContentControl(
            range3, "richTextContentControl1");
        this.customerBindingSource.DataSource = this.Table1.Customer;
        this.customerContentControl.DataBindings.Add("Text", this.customerBindingSource,
            "CompanyName", true, this.customerContentControl.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode);

        this.button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
        this.button2.Click += new EventHandler(button2_Click);
    }
    void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.customerBindingSource.MovePrevious();
    }

    void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.customerBindingSource.MoveNext();
    }
    private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

[Here is a reference to my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2vej.png)

Here are some error messages:

[Here are some error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOGlW.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOGlW.png)

Comment: Can you provide also the error message in your question, please?

Comment: Please give the error message AND the *line of code that triggers it*. Otherwise no one can help you.

Comment: @CindyMeister In this line ` private Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word.Controls.Button button1;`  the `Controls` is reporting an error, I don't know which one of my PIAs is not referenced.

Comment: PLEASE also quote the error *message*. AND include the code that causes the error *IN* your Question. People here generally do *not* care to download and look at people's documents or projects - we get paid for that kind of work.

Comment: Thank you @CindyMeister for your reply,  I took a screenshot of the wrong message and modified my post.